# How can I disable the endIconDrawable default tint mode in my xml layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have the current code below. My drawable toggle color keeps turning to white. The images I have in my drawable are gray and I need them to stay that way. The tint mode problem does not show up when I use `app:passwordToggleDrawable=""`, which is not recommended to use anymore. I would like to use endIconDrawable, so I can use my data binding setup that I have to switch between two different types of drawables resources I have. But, the default tint color which is turning my drawables to white has been a blocker for me. I spent almost a day tyring different things and researching. Any help would be appreciated.
I also noticed, when I do endIconMode ="custom", that's when the default tint mode turns my drawable to white. But, if I don't use endIconMode ="custom". Then the tint doesn't happen, but the custom drawable doesn't show, but instead the default password darwable shows.

I have two selector files that have different drawable images, which is what I'm tiring to show properly based on a condition.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:endIconTint="@null"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the startIconDrawable.

My solution was to set the drawable into the TextInputEditText as drawableLeft with a padding and not to the TextInputLayout.

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout ... >

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableStart="@drawable/my_icon"
      android:drawablePadding="@dimen/my_icon_padding"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```